# Подскажите datepicker у которого есть возможность изменить дату не открыв календарь через стрелки

Tags: javascript

Уже два дня ищу нормальную библиотеку для использования календаря.

Очень много библиотек посмотрел. Мне нужно обычная функциональность и нормальная документация.

Проста надо стрелки поставить рядом с датой чтобы можно было менять день не заходя в календарь как в скрине.

Попробовал следующие библиотеки но безуспешно:

[Date Range Picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#config)

[PickaDate](https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)

[Bootstrap DatePicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

[Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

Но не у одного нету функциональности которое мне надо.Или есть только у них в документации не написано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже придется делать вручную =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ получается так =(

Comment: Но если Вам не нужны премудрости то он выглядит не сложно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  я придумал сейчас напишу ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот собрал Вам пример:

```js
changeDate(0);

function changeDate(dir) {
  let ms = dir*24*60*60*1000 + (+selectedDate.dataset.ms || Date.now());
  selectedDate.dataset.ms = ms;
  selectedDate.innerHTML = new Date(ms).toLocaleDateString();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick=changeDate(-1) ><</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id=selectedDate style="pointer-events:none"></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick=changeDate(-1)>></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Почти. Но нужно еще чтобы при клике на время открылся календарь.Кроме этой функциональности.Отдельно скажу то что вы творите с математикой в одну строку этому нет слов (в хорошем в смысле). :)

Comment: @Demon__ да бросьте Вы, я очень поверхностно понимаю математику, но стараюсь заполнить этот пробел

Comment: Принимаю ответ если будет время добавьте функционал для открытие календаря.Это приветствуется хотя и не обязательно.Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Да будет сложно найти календарь с такими возможностями.

Решение проще чем я думал.

Возьмем календарь **bootstrap-datepicker**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

Я просто добавлю выбранный таймер в `localStorage` и потом при клике на кастомных стрелок буду менять то число дней через `moment` который есть в `localStorage`.Соответственно и будет меняться число  который лежит в `input`.